# Get VPC id from another terraform project

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a terraform project set up an VPC for a region to use for all EKS cluster in that region.
After run `terraform apply` successful, I have these output:

```
Outputs:

all_worker_mgmt_id = "sg-09992bfxxxx13b782"
azs = tolist([
  "us-east-2a",
  "us-east-2b",
  "us-east-2c",
])
public_subnets = [
  "subnet-03ac0xxxxe533b510",
  "subnet-0f91a04168xxxx9c7",
  "subnet-0xxxxcd5cfcaa938c",
]
vpc_cidr_block = "192.168.0.0/16"
vpc_id = "vpc-07e4xxxxxxxx6f616"
```

In another terraform project set up an EKS cluster, I need to extract the `vpc_id` and `public_subnets` to use to configure the cluster.

How can I dynamic get above variable 's values without hardcode in configuration?

And does this document (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/vpc) use for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually keep resources separated in terraform and use `data` to get the resources that were already created, manually of with other terraform projects.

```
locals {
  environment = "test"
}

data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  filter {
    name = "tag:Name"
    values = [local.environment]
  }
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "private_subnets" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.vpc.id

  filter {
    name = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${local.environment}-private-*"]
  }
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "public_subnets" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.vpc.id

  filter {
    name = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${local.environment}-public-*"]
  }
}
```

When you need to get one `public` or `private` subnet, use sort:

```
resource "aws_instance" "gitlab" {
  ...
  subnet_id = sort(data.aws_subnet_ids.public_subnets.ids)[0]
  ...
}
```

The above code will work perfectly if you use the [terraform vpc module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest)

Or, if you want to have a tool that manages all resources at once, you can use [Terragrunt](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/)

Answer (score 1):

Generally you could use [outputs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/output.html) along with `jq` to get the output values:

```
terraform output -json | jq -r '.vpc_id.value'
terraform output -json | jq -rc '.public_subnets.value'
```

or even simpler:

```
terraform output vpc_id
terraform output public_subnets
```

Comment: Tks I can get these output but how can I dynamically pass these variables into the terraform project I set up a EKS cluster use this VPC.

Comment: @ThoQuach It depends on your setup. Pass them using [-var](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#variables-on-the-command-line) parameter.

Comment: You mean we pass through command line when apply, right?
So the code still not change and we can reuse.

Comment: @ThoQuach Yes, you can do this. So in your automatic script you can get outputs from one terraform module/script and pass them as inputs to the next one.